# how to create a custom sort criteria with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I have a table that sorts in jquery and I have one column that I would like to always remain the same while the other columns sort around it. What I want is for the order of the column to always be Great, Bad, Failure while every other column can be sorted and I don't want to the column to sort alphabetically. What is the easiert way for me to do this?

Comment: Which table-sorting plug-in are you using?

Comment: When you say you want the column to "be the same", do you mean that you want to always sort by that column first? (You don't mean that you want the values in that column to remain unchanged as other rows sort, effectively causing them to change what row they go with, right?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to nest a table, one with the column you don't want sorted nest one with the the rest.